# Copy files ending in .exe or .dll

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this is really simple but can't seem to find a solution. Right now I'm using this script:

```
Copy-Item -Path $path\*.dll -Destination $dest
Copy-Item -Path $path\*.exe -Destination $dest
```

Is there a way to get this down to 1 line? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the -include parameter like this:

```
copy-item -path $path\* -destination $dest -include *.dll,*.exe
```